# Is there a problem with this toilet flange or flange installation?

Tags: plumbing, leak, toilet, flange

We have had all sorts of problems with our toilet (the builder and plumber have been out five times). Leaking issues, toilet rocking back and forth, wax rings installed incorrectly.

My question is, does this toilet flange look ok? On the left and right sides, it bulges up...is this normal? Does anything else look defective with it (does it look installed at the proper level)?

[image: Toilet flange]

[image: Toilet flange top]

Comment: It looks warped to me but that could be from them trying to tighten the toilet down. I have had trouble getting toilets set on tile especially with plastic flanges. Some toilets won't seat on a truly flat base because of imperfections in the toilet. In more than 1 case on tile I have bedded the outside edge in thinset using plastic wrap to prevent the thinset from bonding to the toilet itself and wiping all the excess away on the outside.

Comment: "bedded the outside edge in thinset", are you saying you bed the outer perimeter of the toilet itself in thinset? I urge customers to *never* seal around the toilet with anything, as this would surely conceal all signs of a wax ring leak, resulting in eventual catastrophic damage to the floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush with the finished floor is optimal, so it looks OK in that regard.

The warp is a bit concerning, it looks like someone forced it down over a bump or protrusion or maybe over tightened the toilet to it and damaged it (although it would be expected that the toilet itself would break under that amount of stress).

> Leaking issues, toilet rocking back and forth

These things point to a loose flange, loose toilet attachment, or lame application of wax seal. Have you grabbed the flange and pulled on it a bit to ensure it is attached to the pipe and floor properly? I can't see any fasteners in any of the many available bolt holes provided to secure the flange to the floor (although it may be the angle of your pic).

I try to use only cast iron flanges because I have seen many plastic and thin steel ones break. Maybe it's time to call a reputable licensed local plumber (instead of the builder or his "plumber") and bill the builder for whatever repairs the plumber ends up making.

Comment: Yes, the flange is secure. I added another photo. Our previous toilet had a "defect" (I'm not sure what the problem was - my wife was there at the time)...so it could be it was related to over-tightening.